# My device can't play .m4a files

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, music

I've a Xiaomi Redmi 3 Pro.

When I put some .m4a files on my device from my computer, I can't play them. I always have to convert the files from .m4a to .mp3 and then I can listen to them.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try third party players such as MX player or VLC for Android for playing m4a files.

Comment: I downloaded VLC and now the files are working.. thanks!